# Retrieving whole URL, even with ampersands, using _GET

Tags: php, url, get

I made a quick script to retrieve and parse XML. It's simply for internal use and I though that appending the feed URL to the script address would be a convenient way to initialize the script...

> www.example.com/feed_analyzer.php?url=www.example.com/an_xml_feed.xml

Then I simply grab the URL...

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $xml_url = $_GET['url']
}
```

...retrieve the file at $xml_url, parse etc.

All was fine until this URL came along with pesky parameters:

> www.example.com/an_xml_feed.xml?foo=bar&rice=chips

That of course left me with the URL "www.example.com/an_xml_feed.xml"

I have managed to "patch back together" the whole URL using this clunky code:

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
  foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
   $got .= "&".$key."=".$value;
  }
  $xml_url = ltrim($got,'&url=');
}
```

Can someone please suggest a more elegant approach.

Comment: You can certainly hand over anything you like as a request GET argument, however you need to ``urlencode()`` it, otherwise it will collide with the URL parsing itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use this to get the whole query url:

```
ltrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'url=');
```

Comment: Elegant one line solution tested and working, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` is the way to go :)

Comment: OK, but in what fashion?

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  if (!empty($query_string)) {
     list($key, $xml_url) = explode('url=', $query_string); 
     echo $xml_url;
  }
```

}